# Stereo wavs unwantedly combined to polyphonic wav

Tags: field-recording, stereo, wav

I've recentley recorded some stereo atmos's for a job and I have used sound devices wave agent to add meta data, This caused them to be combined to a polyphonic wav, which still plays as a stereo file but when i drag it into pro tools I can only add it as a mono file. When I split the file using wave agent again it just creates 2 identical mono tracks. Can anyone tell me how i am able to convert them back to the original stereo files?

Thanks

Comment: wave agent should be able to split poly wavs

Comment: It shows up in the pro tools workspace as having 2 channels, and when I play it's in stereo but I can only drag into a mono track, any idea what's going on?

Comment: Sorry, no - I've never used Pro Tools.

Comment: *If any admin can transform my message to a comment that would be appreciated (I have less than 50 reputation to do that myself).* @TheSerpent Could you provide an example of such a wave file?

Comment: If playback in ProTools still sounds stereo, you can export out a new file and import back in. No idea other than that.

Answer (score 1):

[Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/) is a free soundfile editing tool that offers many opportunities for purposes like this.

1. Open your file in Audacity.
2. Simply export (Ctrl+Shift+E) it again
3. In the appearing window, define your desired format and quality (should be the original one, you can choose between several non-compressed formats (16bit, 24bit, 32bit)).
4. In the upcoming window, you can then assign new metadata to it.

If this does not result in what you are looking for, you can also split the original stereo file to 2 mono tracks by selecting the dropdown in the big grey box left of the track lane & choosing "Split Stereo to Mono".

Furthermore, there are batch options for Audacity.

I'm not using Pro Tools but have been working with Logic and StudioOne. Audacity has always helped me out. And yes, it is avaliable for Apple, Linux and Windows (in alphabetical order...).